# Issues trying to install AirFlow locally

Tags: python, installation, airflow

I'm new at airflow and I'm trying to install locally, following the instructions on the link below:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html

I'm running this code (as mentioned on the link):

```
# Airflow needs a home. `~/airflow` is the default, but you can put it
# somewhere else if you prefer (optional)
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

# Install Airflow using the constraints file
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.2.5
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
# For example: 3.6
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"
# For example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.5/constraints-3.6.txt
pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"

# The Standalone command will initialise the database, make a user,
# and start all components for you.
airflow standalone

# Visit localhost:8080 in the browser and use the admin account details
# shown on the terminal to login.
# Enable the example_bash_operator dag in the home page
```

and getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\F43555~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12908/3415008398.py", line 3
    export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Someone knows how to deal with it?

I'm running on windows 10, vs code (jupyter notebook).

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow is only supported on Linux and it looks like you're trying to run this on a windows machine.

If you want to install Airflow on Windows you'll need to use something like Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) or Docker. There are some examples around which show you how to do this on WSL (and loads using docker) - [Here is one of them with WSL](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-wsl/).

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that airflow only works on Linux. I can't download ubuntu on my company computer without authorization so I will try docker installation first. Tks!

Comment: No worries! It's a bit painful that you can't install on windows at the moment! Going with Docker is a pretty good alternative though!